# MYSQL query group values of the same key

Tags: mysql

To associate a product with a category in a CMS I created a table in a MySQL database with two columns: **ean** and **cat**

```
9791023507133; category1
9791023507133; category2
9791036317309; category1
9782745929334; category1
9782081286603; category1
9782745943835; category1
```

The same EAN may appear several times, because a product may belong to several categories.

I need to obtain a table with the same 2 columns, but **that ean is unique**, and that cat contains the list of cats found for this ean (separated by a | for example)

```
9791023507133 ; category1|category2
9791036317309 ; category1
9782745929334 ; category1
9782081286603 ; category1
9782745943835 ; category1
```

Is this doable with a MySQL query?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ean, GROUP_CONCAT(cat SEPARATOR '|')
FROM `NoOneEverNamesTheirTableInSqlQuestions`
GROUP BY ean
```

Comment: That's Perfect, thank you very much Bill !!
But how did you guess the name of my table? Are you some kind of wizard??

Comment: It's a gift of mine!